# async logging in python

Tags: python, async-await

Assuming that I use a library that provides the ability to log asynchronously:

```
def _foo():
   # do stuff
   await logger.info("something done.")

async main():
   # do stuff
   await logger.info("something else done.")
   something = foo()
   await logger.shutdown()
```

In this case also foo () must be asynchronous?

Comment: If you are using `await`, the function must be `async`, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary that **`foo`** must be an **async** function but using sync functions will basically block the whole function which to prevent we use **`async`** functions.